# Does WCF XmlSerializerFormat guarantee order of anytype objects after deserialization?

Tags: xml, arrays, wcf, soap, xml-serialization

I do WCF SOAP service from the available wsdl for Java client and use XmlSerializerFormat.
Xml request looks like this

```
<ArrayOfAnyType Xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <anyType xsi:type="xsd:int">100</anyType>
         <anyType xsi:type="xsd:int">200</anyType>
         <anyType xsi:type="xsd:int">300</anyType>
</ArrayOfAnyType>
```

Whether guarantees XmlSerializerFormat, that array elements ArrayOfAnyType be in the same order as in Xml?

Does this code always will give me 100,200,300?

```
foreach(var item in ArrayOfAnyType)
{
    Console.WriteLine((int)item);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the XmlSerializer will maintain the order of arrays (including AnyType) when deserializing XML (as order is important for both XML and arrays).